# Serializing a field of the related model in a model DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer as follows:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prop_post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=PropertyPost.objects.all(),
                                             slug_field='pk')

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'url',
            'photo',
            'prop_post',
        )
```

This works Ok. Now my PropertyPost has a 'owner' field that I need to include in my ImageSerializer.
I was wondering how could I do that. I was thinking it might be like

```
    fields = (
        'url',
        'photo',
        'prop_post',
        'prop_post__owner'
    )
```

but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.
here is my model:

```
class PropertyPost(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='posts4thisowner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Image(models.Model):
    prop_post = models.ForeignKey(
        PropertyPost,
        related_name='images4thisproperty',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_update_image, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Add your models to the question portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to use 'source' and you can use your user serializer to populate the owner fields.

Example:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prop_post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=PropertyPost.objects.all(),
                                             slug_field='pk')

    owner = UserSerializer(source="prop_post.owner")   

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'url',
            'photo',
            'prop_post',
            'owner',
        )
```

Comment: thanks it is working ok, it adds the entire owner model though, is it a way to have just one field of the owner like `owner.email` displayed?

Comment: You can make a special user serializer to serialize only the email field. Or you can try to use CharField and set source to the email field only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SerializerMethodField()` that will achieve the task. 
Since you haven't posted your models and how it's related.
I gave you the normal idea of how to achieve this.
It will be better if you can add the models as well.
I will be able to update the answer accordingly.

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField

class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prop_post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=PropertyPost.objects.all(),
                                         slug_field='pk')
    prop_post_title = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = [
            'url',
            'photo',
            'prop_post',
            'prop_post_title',
        ]

    def get_prop_post_title(self, obj):
        try:

            return obj.prop_post.title
        except:
            return None
```